# HTML5 <img> tag alternative image

Tags: html, image

I was just wondering that in the html img tag

`<img alt = "default image" src = "image">`
is it possible to have a alternate image rather than just text. Or if is it possible to nest the img tag in the alt ""s.

Comment: unsure if it would be possible using pure HTML. Some scripting may be required.

Comment: Alternative under what conditions? The `alt` attribute is primarily meant to be useful when the user does not see images at all, for one reason or another, so that a *textual* alternative is presented.

Comment: I wanted a pictorial alternative than a textual alternative but I've got the answer using the `onError` JavaScript function.

Answer (score 22):

No, you can't put another image in the alt attribute of an `<img>`. You can however use the onerror event to load another image using JavaScript, so if the original image doesn't load, a backup can be loaded.

```js
function standby() {
    document.getElementById('foo').src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'
}
```

```html
<img id="foo" src="notfound.gif" onerror="standby()">
```

Comment: This is more of a hack than an answer, but you can do this (not that you should!):  <img src="image1" alt="image2" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=this.alt;" >

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the alt attribute is supposed to have only text, since it is helpful for screen readers to "read" images.

If what you are searching for is a alternate image when the main one fails, you can do so with some JavaScript.

On this question you can see how to use the onError usage:

[jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)